# How to draw inward spiraling color rainbow in canvas with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, 2d, visualization

I saw this image that I loved and thought it would be really cool to attempt to render it in canvas:

[image]

I've tried drawing arcs radiating from the center of the screen but can't seem to get their paths right. Would love if anyone has ideas on the right approach to start.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't solve it, but you asked for a start. As far as I can tell JS doesn't have a Quadratic Bezier curve (SVGs do, might be more accurate), but you can do a Cubic Bezier curve as follows. Once you have your base coordinates, you'll need to do the math to rotate them around the circle at as many points as you need. Might take some brain power, but it won't be that hard once you get the formula right. Here's the basics of your curve.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(230, 175, 230, 150, 230, 0);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas height=400 width=400></canvas>
```